# writing Dataframe with list to CSV

Tags: r

I am using https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fbRads/fbRads.pdf to import data from facebook marketing API.

One of the fields https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/adgroup/insights/ - `website_purchase_roas` is a list of fields.

How do I put this into a CSV?

```
 website_purchase_roas  date_stop
1    0.673001 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 6.506892 2018-10-11
2    1.369035 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 0.594109 2018-10-11
3    2.084238                                           NULL 2018-10-11
4     1.31209                                           NULL 2018-10-11
5    2.337662                                           NULL 2018-10-11
6    0.996678                                           NULL 2018-10-11
7    1.936385 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 1.482508 2018-10-11
8    2.777778                                           NULL 2018-10-11
9           0                                           NULL 2018-10-11
10   1.994885                                           NULL 2018-10-11
11   2.402023                                           NULL 2018-10-11
12   4.635056 offsite_conversion.fb_pixel_purchase, 5.222421 2018-10-11
13          0                                           NULL 2018-10-11
14   1.990291                                           NULL 2018-10-11
15   6.557377                                           NULL 2018-10-11
16   3.703704                                           NULL 2018-10-11
17   3.038936                                           NULL 2018-10-11
```

So far I have been using

write.table(get(fileName), paste0("/home/rstudio/", fileName), append=TRUE, na = "NA", row.names=FALSE, sep=",", col.names = FALSE)

But of course this isn't capable of handling lists and I need to flatten the data frame first.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fwrite` from the `data.table` package which has a `sep2` argument which determines what to use as a separator for `list` columns.

See `?data.table::fwrite`.

Example:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(01349)
DT = data.table(
  V1 = rchisq(5, 5), 
  l_col = lapply(integer(5L), function(x) rnorm(sample(3L, 1L)))
)

fwrite(DT)
# V1,l_col
# 8.55552022121412,-0.865231813182414
# 1.24426281601847,-0.193327839843266|0.215528624259188|0.347253218410811
# 3.43283896352093,0.87954526007159
# 7.60971421627405,-2.37928159590364
# 8.83757675994184,-0.981183793508651|-1.29924540435512
```

Comment: I get   Column 4's length (28) is not the same as column 1's length (29)

Comment: But what I am actually looking for a way is to convert this list into flat columns of dataframe instead and not have them differentiated with rest of the dataframe columns

Comment: @Simrankaur that's very much not what was asked in your question. Use `unnest` or `as.data.table` or even `toString`, depending on your desired output.

Comment: Thanks. I am new to R. Apologies if I did not phrase my question correctly. Do you mind sharing an example for my use case?

Comment: also, unnest is resulting in multiple rows from a list instead of columns